# In foxpro dbf create multiple column index?

Tags: indexing, odbc, foxpro, dbf

i have a FoxPro container DBC with several DBF tables inside.
The tables have this structure:

```
TableA(id, numbers1, numbers2, numbers3)
```

numbers1, numbers2 and numbers3 are strings with numbers comma separated like this:

```
numbers1 = '01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08' --> 8 numbers
numbers2 = '09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16' --> 8 numbers
numbers3 = '01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15' --> 15 numbers
```

The numbers cant repeat between the same row and in the entire table, so the numbers1 on the top cant appear on numbers1 OR numbers2 in another row.

So, to prevent this... i apply an index on the columns numbersX like this:

```
INDEX ON numbers1 CANDIDATE TAG numbers1
INDEX ON numbers2 CANDIDATE TAG numbers2
INDEX ON numbers3 CANDIDATE TAG numbers3
```

But this... only prevents that there be no duplicates on the same column.. so:

```
RowA.numbers1 cant be equal to RowB.numbers1
```

But this could happen:

```
RowA.numbers1 = RowB.numbers2
```

And i don't want that....

So my question is how can i fix this problem? i think in doing a multiple index on both columns, can be done? i'm thinking more in mysql or sql server, but i dont know if this works on foxpro.

Answer (score 2):

You can not fix this in a simple manner as your table has not been normalized.  You should probably have a table with a pair of columns that what number is associated with a given ID

```
create table tblIDNums ( id int, num int )
```

create unique index on the NUM column so it can never be associated with any OTHER ID except for the first entry it is assigned to unless it gets re-assigned, just update the id column.

Then, insert your records such as

```
insert into tblIDNums ( id, num ) values ( 1, 1 )
insert into tblIDNums ( id, num ) values ( 1, 2 )
insert into tblIDNums ( id, num ) values ( 1, 3 )
insert into tblIDNums ( id, num ) values ( 1, 4 )
insert into tblIDNums ( id, num ) values ( 1, 5 )
insert into tblIDNums ( id, num ) values ( 1, 6 )
insert into tblIDNums ( id, num ) values ( 1, 7 )
insert into tblIDNums ( id, num ) values ( 1, 8 )
insert into tblIDNums ( id, num ) values ( 2, 9 )
insert into tblIDNums ( id, num ) values ( 2, 10 )
insert into tblIDNums ( id, num ) values ( 2, 11 )
insert into tblIDNums ( id, num ) values ( 2, 12 )
insert into tblIDNums ( id, num ) values ( 2, 13 )
insert into tblIDNums ( id, num ) values ( 2, 14 )
insert into tblIDNums ( id, num ) values ( 2, 15 )
insert into tblIDNums ( id, num ) values ( 2, 16 )
```

So now, if you tried to insert an ID 3 with a value of 13 it would fail the insert since 13 is associated with ID 2.  You can't just comma separate expected numeric values as it looks at it as an entire string, not the individual values themselves and knowing if they are sequential, gaps, out of order, etc.

Comment: I'm sorry but i have no chances to create another table for this project... the options i have is to modify the existent one.